# I tried installing the pickle package for Python using (pip install pickle5) and it fails installing the package

Tags: python, machine-learning, installation, pip, pickle

Here is what I tried:

```
pip install pickle5
```

Here is a [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ52a.png) with the error messages.

Here is also the error I get:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for pickle5, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I tried installing and reinstalling Microsoft Visual C++ as suggested in some other posts but it didn't work.

Comment: What is your Python version? Note that the documentation for pickle5 states "It *should* work with Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7"

Comment: As far as I can tell *pickle5* is not meant to be installed on Python > 3.8. If you have a Python higher than 3.8.3 then all the features are already included in the standard library's `pickle`. See the project description: https://pypi.org/project/pickle5/